# I want to add mobile and email icon in Odoo

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-8, odoo-8

I want to add mobile and email icon in Odoo
but it does not show required out put and it show scattered picture.

```html
<div align="left">
    Support Contacts: 
    <i class="icon-mobile-phone icon-large"></i>     
    tempdata  
    <a href="mailto:temp@gmail.com">
        <i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>     
        retail@itsrelevant.com
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div align="left">
    Support Contacts: 
    <i class="fa fa-phone icon-large"></i>

    tempdata

    <a href="mailto:temp@gmail.com">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>

        retail@itsrelevant.com
    </a>
</div>`

use `fa fa-phone` for phone icon and `fa fa-envelope-o` for email icon